# Is there a way of selecting all records of a certain ID after randomly selecting the IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, random, pandas-groupby

I have a number of values per ID in this format:

```
ID  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    A     A    C
1    C     B    B
1    B     D    A
2    C     B    C
2    D     B    A
2    D     A    D
3    A     D    B
3    B     C    C
3    C     B    A
4    A     A    D
4    C     B    C
4    B     B    A
5    D     B    B
5    A     C    C
5    D     C    C
```

I want to randomly select IDs but keep all values per ID, so for example, if I wanted to get 2 random IDs; the outcome would look like this:

```
ID  Var1 Var2 Var3
2    C     B    C
2    D     B    A
2    D     A    D
5    D     B    B
5    A     C    C
5    D     C    C
```

Giving me, ID 2 & 5.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your question with us. Would you mind adding what you have tried so far to your current question in order for others to have a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: df.groupby('ID').random.choice('ID', k =2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy.random.choice to select random values then select them.

```
from numpy.random import choice

nums = choice(df.ID.unique(), 2) # this line selects 2 unique random values from column ID
df_new = df[df['ID'].isin(nums)] # this line selects those 2 random IDs
```

Edit:

please read the comment from ouroboros1. choice has a parameter replace and it should be used.

```
choice(df.ID.unique(), 2, replace=False)
```

Comment: use `choice(df.ID.unique(), 2, replace=False)` if you want to exclude the possibility of selecting a certain ID multiple times. As is, `nums` may look like `array([1, 1], dtype=int64)`, thus leading to a df.shape `(3, 4)`, rather than `(6, 4)`.